# Win7 use one file as a +rw folder/drive/image?

Tags: archiving

I've accumulated a bunch of backup files, documents, images etc over the years, and since I rarely use the files I just keep them in a .RAR file.

Now I need to add a bunch of files to it, remove some, and it's sooo slow. I drag a document into WinRAR and it takes almost 30seconds for it to finish adding the file. I tried extracting all of the files and creating a .RAR file with no compression, just store, but it still takes the same time to add files. The same goes with .ZIP files. I have over ~4000 files but they only take up ~1gb, so I'm guessing it's the amount of files that makes .RAR and .ZIP archives slow.

I'm wondering if there is a solution where I could have one file, that is quick to mount/open, (preferably without bloated third party software), has good read/write times, I'd love it if there would be thumbnail support, but I can live without having thumbnails if the write speeds are great.

**Edit**

Thanks to @Daniel B for showing me the virtual disk method. I've improved this to make it a lot easier for quick access.

1. I created the virtual disk just as in the [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5291/how-to-create-a-virtual-hard-drive-in-windows-7/) in the answer.
2. Next I created 2 mount and unmount .BAT files that are intended for the "Send to.." context menu from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/51174/mount-and-unmount-a-vhd-file-in-windows-explorer-via-a-right-click/)
3. Using [ContextEdit](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/ContextEdit.shtml) I added those two files to the context menu of the .VHD file, instead of having it in the Send to menu for all files

Now it's super easy to mount and unmount that file. It works awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, using Virtual Disks. However, it's not possible to allow fully dynamic growth.

The basic steps are:

1. Fire up Disk Management (accessible via Computer -> Right click -> Manage)
2. Menu Action -> Create VHD
3. Choose "Dynamically expanding" and set the other options to your liking
4. Confirm
5. Create partition on virtual disk

In the virtual disk's context menu, you can also detach it. Use Action -> Attach VHD to reattach it.

To see the procedure in greater details and with pictures, see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5291/how-to-create-a-virtual-hard-drive-in-windows-7/)

**Buuut**: Why not just use a folder? It's roughly a gazillion times faster and doesn't impose any uncalled-for restrictions. Stuffing files in a file is also a bona fide way to accelerate data loss.

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't want to do it this way, but it actually works better than expected, I've updated my question to reflect what I did to make this work much better and faster. Thanks again!